# SSRS textbox rotating incorrectly

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, orientation, server-side-rendering

I have an ssrs chart with two issues.

As you can see in this image: http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Gruff_from_Stack/media/GraphDeployedToServer_zpsxor5d69a.png.html?sort=3&o=0
The Y axis title is facing the wrong direction and not center aligned. Additionally, the PD Hours data set on the bottom has a large gap between it and the graph

Here is an image of that same graph in my SSRS development 'Preview Mode': http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Gruff_from_Stack/media/GraphInDevelopment_PreviewMode_zps64mmf2i2.png.html?sort=3&o=1

I have neither issue.

> Can anybody suggest why the server is rendering differently from my environment?
>
> Note that both the title and PD hours are in text boxes. I am developing in VS 2015 with SSRS 2016 but deploying to an SSRS 2008 r2 server

Let me know if I should clarify anything

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by deploying to our SSRS 2016 server. I do not know what the issue is or why it is resolved in 2016 but at least its working